# Supplied parameters do not match any signature with ionic 2 and firebase

Tags: typescript, ionic2, firebase-authentication

On ionic 2 with typescript I use this firebase function to reset a user password.
The function works well but the console show a bug :

Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target for line : "this.ref.resetPassword({email: credentials.email})"

Can anyone help me to fix it ?

Thanks.

```
    retrievePassword(credentials, _event) {
        _event.preventDefault();
        this.ref.resetPassword({
  email: credentials.email
  // password: credentials.password
}).then((error) =>  {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "INVALID_USER":
        console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error resetting password:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Password reset and email was sent successfully!");
    this.presentToast();
  }
});
```